# How to change the extension name of a file before downloading?

Tags: javascript

I have a video file hosted which looks like this:

> https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0664/3037/0044/files/video

Right now, the video file has no extension at all. Using Javascript, how can I download the file with .mp4 extension. I need a way to change its filename to [filename].mp4 and then download.

I tried the following but it downloads the file without the extension.

```js
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}



downloadURI("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0664/3037/0044/files/video", "video.mp4");
```

Comment: Why can't you use the "download" attribute on your `A` tag? Is it just for renaming? Directly accessing the file system from Java is possible (in chrome) but it takes some doing

Comment: "download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes." and "If the Content-Disposition header has different information from the download attribute, resulting behavior may differ: If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

> `download` only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data:
> schemes. If the `Content-Disposition` header has different information
> from the download attribute, resulting behavior may differ:
>
> If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename
> specified in the `download` attribute.
>  If the header specifies a
> disposition of `inline`, Chrome and Firefox prioritize the attribute
> and treat it as a download. Old Firefox versions (before 82)
> prioritize the header and will display the content inline.

I tried your code on a different origin and it wouldn't download but simply redirect to the URL, also it doesn't send `Content-Disposition`, so it looks like since you're testing this on a different origin, it just redirects to the file link, discarding `download` because it's on a different origin, and your browser is configured to download it. My browser is configured to autoplay videos.
However, I see the URL you provided has CORS *, meaning any origin can access it. So, an alternative you can do is, download the file, and create a blob, then send download to browser.

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
   fetch(uri).then((response) => response.blob())
   .then((blobresp) => {
       var blob = new Blob([blobresp], {type: "octet/stream"});
       var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

       var link = document.createElement("a");
       link.download = name;
       link.href = url;
       document.body.appendChild(link);
       link.click();
       document.body.removeChild(link);
       delete link;
   })
}

downloadURI("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0664/3037/0044/files/video", "video.mp4");
```

Comment: So, if the URL didn’t have CORS *, it not possible  to get a response from the Server?

Comment: @GaneshAdhikari yes, if it doesn't have the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, you can't access it from JavaScript. An alternative could have been writing a server side proxy

Answer (score 0):

`const myRenamedFile = new File([myFile], 'my-file-final-1-really.txt');`

Taken from this website which may be a better at explaining than me:

https://pqina.nl/blog/rename-a-file-with-javascript/

alternatively, there seems to be lots of APIs or Node JS that can manage this. This will allow you to rename the file after it's been downloaded and is now a local file.